# TypeError: dispatch is not a function when I try to test a method using JEST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a method that receives some values as a parameter and then dispatches an action. The problem is that when I shallow my component to test this method, I have an error saying that dispatch is not a function.

TEST:

```
test('it changes the state when submit is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<WizardForm store={store}/>);
    const values = {
    entrySign: 'archivoSign',
    signCertificateFile: 'file',
    signCertificate: 'text',
    entryAuth: 'notArchivoAuth',
    authCertificateFile: 'file',
    authCertificate: 'text'
}
const form = wrapper.instance();
//in this method I get the error
form.submit(values)
```

METHOD:

```
submit(values) {
  var authCertificate = this.checkAuth(values);
  var signCertificate = this.checkSign(values);
  let req = {
    authCertificate: authCertificate,
    signCertificate: signCertificate,
    userId: this.state.userId
  }
  const { dispatch } = this.props
  dispatch({type: 'CERTIFICATES_FETCH_REQUESTED', payload: {req}})
}
```

Can anyone help me? I do not know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so now I have this test:

```
it('works', () => {
const values = {
  username: 'marc',
  name: 'marc',
  email: 'marc@hotmail.com',
  entrySign: 'archivoSign',
  signCertificateFile: 'file',
  signCertificate: 'text',
  entryAuth: 'notArchivoAuth',
  authCertificateFile: 'file',
  authCertificate: 'text'
} 
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  submit
});
const mockedStore = createMockStore();
const WizardFormWrapper = connect(reduxFormReducer, mapDispatchToProps)(WizardForm);
const wrapper = shallowWithStore(<WizardFormWrapper />, mockedStore);
   wrapper.props().submit();

});        
})
```

The problem now I get is: ReferenceError: submit is not defined
Any suggestions @RIYAJ KHAN ?

Comment: Thanks! But my component is connected with redux. The problem is that if I use the default component I can not access to the methods inside the Wrapped Component. That's why I have to export the component without the redux connection as well. 

You can take a look here:

export default connect()(WizardForm);

But if I use this component in my test I can not acces the submit method...

Comment: Can u please share the script where you mocked redux connetivity

Comment: Sorry but I do not get what do you mean.. I am a bit lost

Comment: @marc1161 if your compnent connected then dispatch should available in `submit`.Can please share the code how you connecting the `WizardForm` component

Comment: Yes sure: I am doing this at the end of the file:

export default connect()(WizardForm);

Comment: If you putting at the end of `sometest.js` file then its wrong.In React its fine.but  for the testing,order is matter as you going to use it immediately.Put the `connect` statement before the `test` suite

Comment: `wrapper.props().submit();` added

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having a similar problem with setting up a simple https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922667/typeerror-dispatch-is-not-a-function-when-testing-with-react-create-app-jest-an