# TypeError: dispatch is not a function when testing with react-create-app jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to setup testing on a new project created with react-create-app.  Which now seems to be using React 16 and Jest 3 (which supposedly had some breaking changes, or maybe that was enzime).  I'm getting an error similar to this post [TypeError: dispatch is not a function when I try to test a method using JEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935922/typeerror-dispatch-is-not-a-function-when-i-try-to-test-a-method-using-jest)

> TypeError: dispatch is not a function
>         at App.componentDidMount (src/components/App.js:21:68)

```html
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import { App } from '../components/App';
import configureStore from '../state/store/configureStore';

window.store = configureStore({
  slider: {
    mainImageIndex: 0,
    pageNum: 1,
    perPage: 4,
  },
});

const appTest = (
  <Provider store={window.store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

describe('App', () => {
  it('should render without crashing', () => {
    mount(appTest);
  });
});
```

Originally I just tried to do this:

```html
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import { App } from '../components/App';


describe('App', () => {
  it('should render without crashing', () => {
    mount(<App />);
  });
});
```

Which threw this error

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Form(SearchForm))". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop

**Code for App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { searchPhotos } from '../state/actions/searchPhotos';
import { setMainImageIndex, setFirstPage } from '../state/actions/slider';
import Slider from './Slider';
import SearchForm from './SearchForm';
import Error from './Error';
import '../styles/App.css';

export class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(searchPhotos(window.store));
  }

  searchPhotosSubmit = () => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(setFirstPage());
    dispatch(setMainImageIndex(0));
    dispatch(searchPhotos(window.store));
  }

  render() {
    const { fetchError } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Flickr Slider in React.js</h1>
          <SearchForm onSubmit={this.searchPhotosSubmit} />
        </header>
        {!fetchError ? <Slider /> : <Error />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  fetchError: state.fetchError,
  form: state.form,
  slider: state.slider,
}))(App);
```

Comment: can you include `App` component code?

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz thanks for looking, App code added above.  The rest of the code is here: https://github.com/pixelwiz/reactjs-flickr-slider-search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please not that you export both presentational component (as named export) and container component (as default export) in `App.js`. Then in your tests you import and use the presentational component using:

```
import { App } from '../components/App';
```

but you should import connected container component instead using:

```
 import App from '../components/App'; // IMPORTANT! - no braces around `App`
```

Since you're using component that is not connected to Redux store `dispatch` prop is not injected as prop. Just use correct import and it should work.
For more details about importing default and named exports please check this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). About presentational and container components you can read [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#presentational-and-container-components).

Comment: OMG, such a simple thing.  Thank you!  15 years ago it was all searching for a missing semicolon in Java, I guess now it's about the curly brackets.  I'm still getting an error though, although now it's a Network Error.  I probably need to use nock to mock the API call or something

Comment: actually if I switch back to shallow from then the test passes, yay.

Comment: Glad I could help you :)

Comment: The answer helped me , I was also facing the same issue